# Nginx не находит индексный файл

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер

файл конфигурации

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/franchise.landing/html;

        server_name xn--80aaudyq1a9a.xn--80apgfh0ct5a.xn--p1ai www.xn--80aaudyq1a9a.xn--80apgfh0ct5a.xn--p1ai;

        location / {
                index index.html;
                
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        
        }
}
```

cимволическая ссылка была сделана командой:

```
   sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/xn--80aaudyq1a9a.xn--80apgfh0ct5a.xn--p1ai /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

в итоге я получаю 404. Подскажите в чем дело, что не так я делаю?

Comment: Читайте в логах nginx почему он решил выдать 404

Comment: В location оставьте только try_files, index вынесите

Comment: В логах пишет что Permision denided, почему?

Comment: @Istinnavvine в `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` есть строка `user nginx;` ?

Comment: вместо user nginx стоит user www-data

Comment: А у пользователя www-data есть доступ на чтение каталога /var/www/franchise.landing/html и всех родительских каталогов?

Comment: Да это все проставленно